# Swift 2 check before change page

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning to create apps in Xcode. I would like to create some error checking on a page. If a user tries to change the page and they've made changes to some text I'd like to stop them. I have variable in place that is set to true if changes are made, but I don't know how to use it.

Is there an override function that can be used for page change or something? I would have thought I'd be able to add it to the button that you press to change the page, but that isn't showing in my navigation bar.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    print("Hello")
    if count == 0 {
        print("No changesMade")
        return true
    } else {
        print("\(count) Changes Made")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a segue then the easiest way is to implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` function in your view controller.  This returns a boolean - true if the segue should continue and false if it shouldn't.  You can also update a message field or display an alert in this function

Comment: Thanks will give it a google on how to implement in the code. Cheers

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you have tried?

Comment: I've added the code to my original question, phew. That was hard going!

Answer (score 0):

Say your boolean flag is named `editingBegan`, and you set it to true after a user started editing, and back to false after the user saved, you can implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifer:`, and inside just say `return !editingBegan`.  If you're currently editing the segue will just get skipped.

Comment: That's great, where should I put this in the code? I'm away from my Mac at the moment. Will have s Google to see how to implement. Thanks

Comment: Can't seem to get it to call the override function?? Added code to original question

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific or post a snippet of your code here ?

From my understanding here, you can at least do three things for preventing changes:

- prevent changes using [property observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). If you are using some
  properties inside your page, define property observers to monitor
  changes in a property’s value.
- prevent changes using textfield delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` if user is editing something in textfield
- prevent changes using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` if user is about to have segue triggered